# Rendering issue in safari on mac os x, could be z-index issue

Tags: css, macos, safari, rendering, z-index

Safari seems to have a very weird rendering problem, that may be caused by a z-index issue, but i can't find what.

- This page (the homepage), when scrolling down, has no problems:
  http://www.sigin.be/home.php
- This page (and every other page except the homepage) shows the error. When scrolling down (let the large background img load first) you will see a white button 'realisaties' scrolling up, but not the content, this appears some time after scrolling. http://www.sigin.be/promotie.php

What could be causing that?

Comment: show your code having issue.

Comment: that's the problem, i don't know where to look... it's clearly a safari rendering issue and not a coding issue. Only safari has this problem, chrome and other browsers work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here was to add a negative z-index on the big background box containing the fixed position element.

> z-index:-1;